# Get a data from SQL as a json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

can you tell me how to make 
`DB::table()->where()->get()` result into a JSON script?. In this script I want get a row as a result

Comment: if you want to convert the result to json, you can use `toJson()`.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Can you show me the example?

Comment: just `return DB::table()->where()->get();` and you get json..

Comment: $result = DB::table.......

then : return response()->json($result, 200)

Answer (score 0):

`DB::table('users')->get()->toJson()` should be enough. Ref [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-tojson)
 If you are making API, use [Eloquent resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources).